# Using Bubblesort and a comparator function to sort an array of Structs

Tags: c, sorting, bubble-sort

I am trying to write a program that compares the time it takes to sort an array of struct Record using both qsort() and a bubblesort algorithm using comparator functions. The user inputs what sorting method they want to use and what member of the struct they would like to sort.

```
struct Record {
int seqnum;
float threat;
unsigned int addrs[2];
unsigned short int ports[2];
char dns_name[NUMLTRS];
};
```

My qsort() works flawlessly, so I believe my comparator function is correct. However, when using bubblesort it does not sort correctly. Here is an example of one of my comparator functions (seqnum).

```
int SeqNumCompare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    struct Record *sa, *sb;

    sa = (struct Record *) a;
    sb = (struct Record *) b;

    if (sa->seqnum < sb->seqnum) return -1;
    else if (sa->seqnum > sb->seqnum) return 1;
    else return 0;
}
```

And here is my bubblesort function.

```
void bubblesort(struct Record *ptr, int records,
    int (*fcomp)(const void *, const void *))
{
    int i, j;
    struct Record temp;
    for (i = 1; i < records; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < records - i; j++) {
            if (fcomp(ptr + j, ptr + j + 1)) {
                temp = ptr[j];
                ptr[j] = ptr[j + 1];
                ptr[j + 1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I feel like this should definitely work, but the array is incorrectly sorted after the function is called. I've debugged for hours, and can't seem to find anything that makes sense to change. Can you see any glaring errors in my bubblesort code?

The bubblesort function is called in the main function like this:

```
if (sort_type == 2)   // bubble sort
{
    start = clock();
    if (sort_field == 1)
        bubblesort(rec_ptr, num_records, SeqNumCompare);
    else if (sort_field == 2)
        bubblesort(rec_ptr, num_records, ThreatCompare);
    else if (sort_field == 3)
        bubblesort(rec_ptr, num_records, AddrCompare);
    else if (sort_field == 4)
        bubblesort(rec_ptr, num_records, DNSNameCompare);
    end = clock();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you check the return value of `fcomp` and make the swap only if the return value is 1 (not -1)?

Comment: Wow, yes you are right. That fixed it. I changed the fcomp statement to

    if (fcomp(ptr + j, ptr + j + 1) > 0). Thanks so much